# Assimp Error when loading model in the browser ( WASM )

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten, assimp

I am trying to load a .glb 3d model (glb is the binary version of gltf) using Assimp ... in a browser.

I am using cmake.
Assimp is built with the following Options :

```
SET(ASSIMP_INSTALL ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
SET(ASSIMP_BUILD_TESTS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
SET(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
SET(ASSIMP_NO_EXPORT ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
SET(ASSIMP_BUILD_ALL_IMPORTERS_BY_DEFAULT OFF CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
SET(ASSIMP_BUILD_GLTF_IMPORTER ON CACHE BOOL "" FORCE)
add_subdirectory(vendor/assimp)

include_directories(vendor/assimp/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} assimp ${ASSIMP_LIBRARIES})

if(EMSCRIPTEN)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-O3")
    target_link_options(
        ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
        "-sMIN_WEBGL_VERSION=2"
        "-sLLD_REPORT_UNDEFINED=1"
        "-sFORCE_FILESYSTEM=1"
        "-sALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1"
        "-sTOTAL_MEMORY=60MB"
        "-sUSE_GLFW=3"
        "-sUSE_WEBGL2=1"
    )
    set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
        PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".js"
        LINK_FLAGS "--bind --embed-file ../Resources"
    )
endif()
```

The project build goes fine with both Windows and Emscripten.
Windows .exe loads the model correctly, but the browser version throws this pretty non descript error

```
Uncaught 13062512
```

the .glb file is in the /Resources directory that I "embed" at linking stage. Other resources ( textures mainly) are correctly loaded from this directory too. So this is not a file access issue.

I have also tried loading the file asynchronously using emscripten_async_wget() function, but I get the same error.

Note that I am already able to load binary 3d meshes, but only in a very basic custom format of mine.
Assimp would be a big step up from that.

(...After some reading on Assimp docs)
There a method : Assimp::Importer::SetIOHandler which might be able to help me ? Apparently I would need to provide a custom implementation of IOSystem ,IOFile and IOStream. Which looks like a daunting task to me...
Could this even solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation and assumptions**

I came across the same issue. According to comments I've seen in other places, the issue is that the Assimp lib uses exception handling to manage code flow. Therefore, in the case of ***.glb** files, the **GLTF version 1 importer** attempts to read the file data. If it cannot interpret it, it would throw an exception which would be handled by moving the operation to the **GLTF version 2 importer** which ought to then correctly process the data.

Emscripten, for reasons beyond me at this point, cannot predictably handle the exception. Regardless of enabling exception handling in the WASM build via any of the following flags as documented in the Emscripten documentation.

```
-fexceptions -sASSERTIONS -O0 -g3
```

**Workaround/HACK**

In my tests, the following allows correct processing of ***.glb** files in WASM via Emscripten. You would however have to recompile the Assimp lib using Emscripten.

In the file "***code/Common/ImporterRegistry.cpp***", comment out the following line of code;

```
out.push_back(new glTFImporter());
```

This removes the **GLTF Version 1 importer** from the importers list. Thus ***.glb** files would default to the **GLTF Version 2 importer** instead. Downside is you cannot process **GLTF Version 1** files anymore (they are old and it is your choice).

BONUS :) - After commenting out that line, I built the project using the CMake via Emscripten.

```
emcmake cmake -S . -B build && emmake make -C build
```

**Note**

I have tried toggling CMake options as suggested by Assimp documentation or set #defines to disable the **GLTF Version 1 importer**. All those attempts result in some or other part of the Assimp lib not compiling or running. Hence this is a hack.

All this was performed on **Assimp v5.2.5** and **Emscripten 3.1.26**